# How to get correct epoch value of a timestamp column in Netezza?

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, database-migration, netezza

My Netezza server is in EDT (UTC -4:00) timezone.

I have a table containing a timestamp column. In my select query, I want to get epoch directly from the value of this timestamp column.

For example,

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW()), NOW();
```

Consider NOW() as the column with timestamp type. Above query returns:

```
1594810500  2020-07-15 10:55:00
```

*1594810500* is supposed to be the epoch value of *2020-07-15 10:55:00* date in EDT.

But when I cross verified the value epoch value [here](https://codechi.com/dev-tools/date-to-millisecond-calculators/)(use timezone as America/Detroit), it gives following output:

```
Wed Jul 15 2020 06:55:00 GMT-0400
```

I was expecting the output would be *2020-07-15 10:55:00*, which is current time in EDT.

What am I doing wrong? How to get correct epoch value?

Comment: I think your `now()` value is really in UTC.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But now() is returning the current date of Detroit area (EDT) and not the UTC. I ran this around 25 minutes ago. And time in Detroit was 10:55 AM then. You can verify. So now() is not returning time in UTC.